# Replace values based on index pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, replace

I'm working with a dataset, from which a subset has initial values and final values. I created an `id` that lets me identify those observations, so after applying this:

```
df['aux']=df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep=False)

df_dup=df_dup[df_dup.aux==True]
df_dup.sort_values(by='id').reset_index(inplace=True)
```

I get something like this:

```
index     id    status    value
  88      1    'initial'    8
  95      1    'final'      12
  63      2    'initial'    9
  52      2    'final'      13
```

What I want to achieve is to replace the final value in the initial value:

```
index     id    status    value
  88      1    'initial'    12
  95      1    'final'      12
  63      2    'initial'    13
  52      2    'final'      13
```

I tried several things, my last attempt was this:

```
df_dup[df_dup.status=='initial'].reset_index().value= \
df_dup[df_dup.status=='final'].reset_index().value
```

But that fills `initial` values with `nan`:

```
index     id    status    value
  88      1    'initial'    nan
  95      1    'final'      12
  63      2    'initial'    nan
  52      2    'final'      13
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) - it also replace unique values of `id`, but it return same value:

```
df['value'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('last')
print (df)
   index  id     status  value
0     88   1  'initial'     12
1     95   1    'final'     12
2     63   2  'initial'     13
3     52   2    'final'     13
```

If want replace only duplicated `id` rows (reason many unique values, so better performance):

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep=False)
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df[mask].groupby('id')['value'].transform('last')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, both your answer and Wen's worked, but I find yours a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Without `groupby` and base on your `drop_duplicates`

```
df.value=df.id.map(df.drop_duplicates('id',keep='last').set_index('id').value)
df
Out[436]: 
   index  id     status  value
0     88   1  'initial'     12
1     95   1    'final'     12
2     63   2  'initial'     13
3     52   2    'final'     13
```